# Higher order types in OCaml (phantom types subtyping)

Tags: ocaml, higher-kinded-types, phantom-types

I'm using phantom types to emulate the state of a stack, as a wrapper module for ocaml-lua (Lua communicates with C/OCaml through a stack). Small code example:

```
type 's t
type empty
type 's table
type top

val newstate : unit -> empty t           (* stack empty *)
val getglobal : empty t -> top table t   (* stack: -1 => table *)
```

Certain stack operations are possible on both tables and array-tables (no real arrays in Lua); some aren't. So if I have types

```
type 's table
type 's array
```

I want a kind like table-or-array for functions that operate on both types, but still being able to forbid e.g. `rawgeti` (array operation) on tables. `objlen` is a stack operation that returns the "length" of the element at the top of the stack. This element can be both table or array-table. At the moment, the wrapper function is defined as follows:

```
val objlen : (top table) t -> int
```

What I want is

```
val objlen : (top table-or-array) t -> int
```

That is, `array` and `table` is subtypes of `table-or-array`.

Any ideas?

Regards
Olle

**Edit**

After considerations, I came up with this:

```
module M : sig
  type ('s, 't) t

  (* New Lua state with empty stack *)
  val newstate : unit -> (unit, unit) t

  (* Get table *)
  val getglobal : ('a) t -> ([< `table | `string | `number | `fn], 'a) t

  (* Get array index and put "anything" on top of stack *)
  val rawgeti : ([`table], 'a) t -> ([< `table | `string | `number | `fn], [`table] * 'a) t

  (* String on top of stack *)
  val tostring : ([`string], _) t -> string

  (* Table or array-table on top of stack *)
  val objlen : ([`table], _) t -> int

  val pop : ('a, 'b * 'c) t -> ('b, 'c) t
end = struct
  type top
  type ('s, 't) t = string      (* Should really be Lua_api.Lua.state *)

  (* Dummy implementations *)
  let newstate () = "state"
  let gettable s = s
  let getarray s = s
  let rawgeti s = s
  let tostring s = "Hello phantom world!"
  let objlen s = 10
  let pop s = s
end
```

The stack at type level should now know neither more nor less than the stack itself. E.g. rawgeti will push on stack any type.

Comment: What about `type ('s, 't) t val objlen : (top, [< \`table | \`array]) t -> int`?

Comment: Actually the type `[< \`table | \`array]` is the same as `[\`table | \`array]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following structure?

```
type ('data, 'kind) t
type array_kind
type stack_kind

(* use tuples as type-level lists:
   (a * (b * (c * unit))) for the stack of type-shape [a;b;c] *)
val newstate : unit -> (unit, stack) t
val getglobal : (unit, stack) t -> (top * unit, stack) t

val objlen : (top * 'a, 'k) t -> int
```

This uses polymorphism (on `'k`) to express that "any kind is
fine". Using polymorphic variants, it is possible to use subtyping
instead, but I would rather advise *against* it, because it is more
complex and its interaction with GADTs (which you want to use
internally to implement your phantom-types signature, or maybe
directly expose GADTs) is more problematic.

PS: this is exactly how the standard [Bigarray](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.html) module uses "kind types" for a similar purpose.

Edit: the formulation above is a bit awkward as polymorphic variant also use polymorphism (subtyping being used in restricted specific cases), and it's possible to only use polymorphism in type-level variants. My remark about excessive complexity of this solution still stands.

Comment: I think you may need GADTs to safely implement your internal operations.

Comment: A small note: You can still emulate subtypes using tuples and parametric polymorphism with a tree-like type structure (described here: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~mtf/research/phantom-subtyping/jfp06/jfp06.pdf).

Comment: Meh, that encoding is horrible. That's nice in theory, but I think that's going too far in practice, giving code that won't be maintainable or understandable by others.